# What resources are there for learning Romanian verb conjugation?

Tags: romanian

I'm currently learning Romanian language, and I have a question about the right conjugation of the verb 'to work', which is 'a lucra'. On [this site](https://www.conjugare.ro/romana/conjugarea-verbului-lucra), on the first tense, it's 'eu lucru'. But on [another one](http://cumsescrie.ro/conjugarea-verbului-a-lucra/), it's written 'eu lucrez'.

On Context.Reverso, I found example for both ['eu lucru'](https://context.reverso.net/traducere/romana-engleza/eu...+lucru) and ['eu lucrez'](https://context.reverso.net/traducere/romana-engleza/eu...+lucrez), which are both translated as 'I work'.

My Moldovan (Republic of Moldova) relatives are saying to me that 'eu lucru' doesn't exist. But I'm not sure if it doesn't exist at all or because this form is uncommon in Moldova.

Which one is the good form? Are both forms valid? Is one of the conjugation a Moldovan form? I can't find the answer in any Romanian learning resources I have. **Can you point me to good resources you use, either English or French ones, especially about conjugation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, yes, the only form that is correct for the conjugation of the verb "to work" ("a lucra") is ***Eu lucrez***, and the one with *Eu lucra* is completely wrong. In fact, below is the conjugation of this verb for all the grammatical persons:

```
  Eu lucrez

  Tu lucrezi

  El/Ea lucrează

  Noi lucrăm

  Voi lucrați

  Ei lucrează
```

As for which website is better... I don't recommend the first one, that told you about the erroneous 'Eu lucra'. The latter looks good.

Comment: Welcome to LL.SE! You might want to mention if you are a native speaker or otherwise quite good with the language to add credibility to your answer.